# Does hashmap in JDK 8 resizes itself again after the entry objects in a bucket decreases from the threshold.?

Tags: java, dictionary, linked-list, hashmap, binary-search-tree

I came across a blog where changes and performance improvements of hashmap were given in JDK8.

> From JDK 1.8 onwards HashMap has introduced an improved strategy to deal with high collision rate. Since a poor hash function e.g. which always return location of same bucket, can turn a HashMap into linked list, i.e. converting get() method to perform in O(n) instead of O(1) and someone can take advantage of this fact, Java now internally replace linked list to a binary true once certain threshold is breached. This ensures performance or order O(log(n)) even in the worst case where a hash function is not distributing keys properly.

In JDK 8, we all know that whenever a threshold value is reached, the linked list re-sizes itself to a binary tree. I wanted to know whether the binary tree will re-size itself into a linked list, again when nodes become less than the threshold number.?

It was asked to me in an interview to which I said, no, as it will not keep re-sizing itself every time there is a change in number. Am I right?

Blogs for reference:

1. http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/07/java-optimization-empty-arraylist-and-Hashmap-cost-less-memory-jdk-17040-update.html
2. http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-hashmap-works-in-java.html

Comment: As the answer mentions, that interview question is very strange, as you would have to have seen the actual source code to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is part of a comment in the `HashMap` source:

```
 * Because TreeNodes are about twice the size of regular nodes, we
 * use them only when bins contain enough nodes to warrant use
 * (see TREEIFY_THRESHOLD). And when they become too small (due to
 * removal or resizing) they are converted back to plain bins.
```

Looking down further, I see this:

```
/**
 * The bin count threshold for using a tree rather than list for a
 * bin.  Bins are converted to trees when adding an element to a
 * bin with at least this many nodes. The value must be greater
 * than 2 and should be at least 8 to mesh with assumptions in
 * tree removal about conversion back to plain bins upon
 * shrinkage.
 */
static final int TREEIFY_THRESHOLD = 8;

/**
 * The bin count threshold for untreeifying a (split) bin during a
 * resize operation. Should be less than TREEIFY_THRESHOLD, and at
 * most 6 to mesh with shrinkage detection under removal.
 */
static final int UNTREEIFY_THRESHOLD = 6;
```

So the answer to the question is "yes and no".  It doesn't resize itself when the size drops below the *same* threshold, but it does resize when it falls below a different threshold.

I don't understand why you would be asked this in an interview--does the company you're applying to really expect you to have memorized the source code of the Java libraries?

Comment: */me nods ...* Every now and then, you run into a company who thinks that "a job interview" is an excuse, either "to give you an IQ test," or to engage in a game of "Trivial Pursuit," both at your expense. ### In any and every such situation, I feel absolutely no qualms in looking the questioner squarely in the eye and answering, "I don't have any idea." (**Not:** *"I'm sorry, but ..."*)  ## Now, having said that, maybe the interviewer is just trying to see, "does this candidate have any 'horse sense?'"  In which case, "use best judgment."

Comment: The question says *"In JDK 8, we all know that..."*, but I'd say that very few people (relatively speaking) know that `HashMap` has been optimized in Java 8 to use a binary tree behind a *single* hash bucket to improve performance in the rare occurred of high collision. What *is* known by a lot more people, is that a `HashMap` will resize the *number* of hash buckets as the map grows, so I think perhaps OP misunderstood the interview question.

Comment: @ajb Well we were discussing hashmaps and its internal implementation so he might have thought about it. But again, I would like to ask suppose the threshold number is 8, so i do map.put() to make total number of nodes for same key be 9, it will re-size itself to  binary tree. What if I now remove 2 nodes to make the threshold number as 7 again. will it re-size to linked list? and what if I add 2 more nodes again to make total number of nodes in it as 9. Will it keep on re-sizing itself??

Comment: @Andreas : Well I never mis-understood the question. Even the discussion we had is given in the above comment of mine for ajb

Comment: @dgupta3091 Did you even look at the answer? The "UNTREEIFY" threshold is 6, so it won't revert to linked list until it drops that low, so why are you asking about 7, when that is still clearly above the threshold? Also, please stop calling it "resize", since it's not a resizing operation. It switches the hash bucket from using a linked list implementation to using a binary tree implementation. It's not the *size* that is being changed, it's the *implementation*.

Comment: @Andreas: I intended to ask my comment before the post was modified.

Answer (score 0):

Binary TreeNode present in a an individual bin/bucket will get untreeify during resize or removal process. But capacity, threshold & overall size of the internal Table will not shrink if associated map elements gets removed.

Note: Java 8 onward HashMap is implementing power of 2 expansion using bitwise operators to maintain constant time performance of basic operations. Whenever map size exceeds threshold it does rehashing. During this resize/expansion a Tree present in a bin will be split into loBit/hiBit Tree & untreeifies the same if too small, moves hiBit Node head to new Table index with power of two offset